# Concurrently call several Spring microservice URLs

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot application that will call several microservice URLs using the `GET` method. These microservice URL endpoints are all implemented as `@RestController`s. They don't return `Flux` or `Mono`.

I need my application to capture which URLs are **not** returning 2xx HTTP status.

I'm currently using the following code to do this:

```
List<String> failedServiceUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String serviceUrl : serviceUrls.getServiceUrls()) {
            try {

                
                ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.getForEntity(serviceUrl, String.class);
                
                if (!response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    failedServiceUrls.add(serviceUrl);
                }

            } catch (Exception e){
                failedServiceUrls.add(serviceUrl);
            }
            
        }

        // all checks are complete so send email with the failedServiceUrls.
        mail.sendEmail("Service Check Complete", failedServiceUrls);
    }
```

The problem is that each URL call is slow to respond and I have to wait for one URL call to complete prior to making the next one.

How can I change this to make the URLs calls be made concurrently? After all call have completed, I need to send an email with any URLs that have an error that should be collected in `failedServiceUrls`.

**Update**

I revised the above post to state that I just want the calls to be made concurrently. I don't care that `rest.getForEntity` call blocks.

Comment: As far as I know you can just create a couple of Completable Futures and then you can wait for them all to finish their job whenever you want

Comment: Do you need non-blocking implementation, or you need parallel execution?

Comment: Do you want them concurrently and non-blocking or both things? Because CompletableFuture would offer concurrency, but not nio.

Comment: The answer may depend a lot of clarifications in your question regarding concurrency and NIO. One simple solution could be to pass NIO a request factory to your RestTemplate (e.g. [Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.html)) is NIO. But there are plenty of other options depending on what you meant.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the executor service in your code, you can call all microservices in parallel this way:

```
// synchronised it as per Maciej's comment:
failedServiceUrls = Collections.synchronizedList(failedServiceUrls);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(serviceUrls.getServiceUrls().size());

    List<Callable<String>> runnables = new ArrayList<>().stream().map(o -> new Callable<String>() {
      @Override
      public String call() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = rest.getForEntity(serviceUrl, String.class);
        // do something with the response

        if (!response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
          failedServiceUrls.add(serviceUrl);
        }

        return response.getBody();
      }
    }).collect(toList());

    List<Future<String>> result = executorService.invokeAll(runnables);
    for(Future f : result) {
      String resultFromService = f.get(); // blocker, it will wait until the execution is over
    }
```

Comment: You’re modyfing `failedServiceUrls` from many threads concurrently. To avoid race condition the access must be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make calls concurrently and you don't care about blocking threads you can:

1. wrap the blocking service call using `Mono#fromCallable`
2. transform `serviceUrls.getServiceUrls()` into a reactive stream using `Flux#fromIterable`
3. Concurrently call and filter failed services with `Flux#filterWhen` using Flux from 2. and asynchronous service call from 1.
4. Wait for all calls to complete using `Flux#collectList` and send email with invalid urls in `subscribe`

```java
void sendFailedUrls() {
        Flux.fromIterable(erviceUrls.getServiceUrls())
                .filterWhen(url -> responseFailed(url))
                .collectList()
                .subscribe(failedURls -> mail.sendEmail("Service Check Complete", failedURls));
    }

    Mono<Boolean> responseFailed(String url) {
        return Mono.fromCallable(() -> rest.getForEntity(url, String.class))
                .map(response -> !response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());

    }
```

**Blocking calls with Reactor**

Since the underlying service call is blocking it should be executed on a dedicated thread pool. Size of this thread pool should be equal to the number of concurrent calls if you want to achieve full concurrency. That's why we need `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

See: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#faq.wrap-blocking

**Better solution using WebClient**

Note however, that blocking calls should be avoided when using reactor and spring webflux. The correct way to do this would be to replace `RestTemplate` with `WebClient` from Spring 5 which is fully non-blocking.

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-webclient.html